# Compare Same Function Output in different moments

Tags: java, multithreading

I've trouble with a comparison between the same function output but in different moments.

```
public int Get_CSV_number_lane()
{
   return csvfile.numberlane(); //this func return number of lane in csv file
}
```

In my main form I want to save this value and open a `Thread`. This `Thread` checks `if (old saved value != new value){do something}`

```
int number_of_lane = Get_CSV_number_lane();

Thread()
{
    if(number_of_lane != Get_CSV_number_lane())
    {
       println("number of lane changes");
       number_of_lane = Get_CSV_number_lane();
    }
}
```

I have a function that return the line of a CSV file. During the execution this file can change. I have a `Thread` that checks if the old value (line of CVS at start) is different from the new value (line of CSV now) and does something. The problem is this check: old value is always the new value.

My question then is, how can I fix that, how can I store the old value and check with new one?

Comment: Besides the style issues (e.g. the empty and thus unnecessary else block, the method names etc. - see the Java code conventions for more info) what's your problem? I don't get it.

Comment: i didn't post all the code cause is so long... sorry for that..
just that:

- i have a function that return the lane of a csv file
- during the execution this file can change
- i have a thread that check if( the old value (lane of csv at start) is different from the new value (lane of csv now) ).. do something

the problem is this check: old value is everytime the new value, so how can i fix that, how can i store the old value and check with new one ?

Comment: Why don't you store it in the thread? Your example looks odd but I assume `Thread()` means you're creating a new thread instance so why don't you pass the original/old value to it and store it there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with ExecutorService, you can use a similar type of it - ScheduledExecutorService:  `An ExecutorService that can schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically.` With ScheduledExecutorService you can start one thread to check periodically your value and then you can compare it with the old value. Here is the tutorial how to use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html)